# Python re.compile between two html tags

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

This should be quite straightforward but I can't quite twig it. I want to get the name from this html string:

```
  soup =   </ul>
  Brian
  <p class="f">
```

I've tried:

```
namePattern = re.compile(r'(?<=</ul>)(.*?)(?<=<p)')
rev.reviewerName = re.findall(namePattern,  str(soup))
```

and

```
namePattern = re.compile(r'</ul>(.*?)<p')
```

Can you tell me how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Is this the complete string you are having?

Comment: No, there is more, do I need to show it?

Comment: Since this is tagged `BeautifulSoup`, I'm a little surprised that you're trying to use regular expressions to get what's after the `</ul>`.  For example, something like `s.find("p", {"class": "f"}).previous.strip()` should return `"Brian"`.  [Given only the bit that you've shown, I mean.]

Comment: Thanks DSM, I wasn't aware of that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `.` doesn't match newlines. You need to specify [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) as the second argument to [`re.compile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile).

Note that this will include the newlines as part of your capture group. If you don't want that, you can explicitly match them with `\s*`:

```
In [5]: re.findall(r'</ul>\s*(.*?)\s*<p', s)
Out[5]: ['Brian']
```